# How to handle the evaluation of functions on staggered ghost nodes?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

I have a convection-diffusion-reaction steady state PDE in the form
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{u_0(x)}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left( \mathcal{D}(z) \frac{\partial C}{\partial z} + \mathcal(z){A}C\right) + \mathcal{R}(z)C\right) + S(x,z)
$$
on $(x,z)\in[0,X]\times[0,H]$ with the following boundary conditions on three of the four boundaries
$$
C(0,z) = C_0, \phantom{A}\frac{\partial C}{\partial z}(x,H) = 0, \phantom{A}\textrm{and}\phantom{A} K(0) \frac{\partial C}{\partial z}(x,0) = aC - b(x)
$$
I can construct a finite difference scheme that boils down to looking of the form
$$
E_{ij}C_{i+1,j+1} + F_{ij}C_{i+1,j} + G_{ij}C_{i+1,j-1} = A_{ij}C_{i,j+1} + B_{ij}C_{i,j} + D_{ij}C_{i,j-1} + \mathcal{H}_{ij}
$$
For the nodes located at $j=0$, (I write schemes indexed starting with 0), I'll have
$$
E_{i,0}C_{i+1,1} + F_{i,0}C_{i+1,0} + G_{i,0}C_{i+1,-1} = A_{i,0}C_{i,1} + B_{i,0}C_{i,0} + D_{i,0}C_{i,-1} + \mathcal{H}_{i,0}
$$

In the derivation of the scheme, of which I omitted, the terms $D_{i,0}$ and $G_{i,0}$, will  require the evaluation of $\mathcal{D}(-\frac{\Delta z}{2})$ and $\mathcal{A}(-\frac{\Delta z}{2})$. Since these are outside of my physical domain, what are some sensible approaches to evaluating these functions there? I've only briefly read into Ghost Fluid Methods and don't know if these have anything to do with this kind of issue.

Note: This question was originally posted in Math Stack Exchange but got very little attention.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluation out of bounds is related to boundary conditions. Doesn't the boundary treatment for $C$ already indicate a way to handle the coefficients? If not, I would use some way that extends the coefficients somehow smooth, e.g. by either repeating the value on the boundary or linear extraploation using values on a small neighborhood.

Comment: The functions are not defined for real number outputs outside one of the boundaries. I'll try linear extrapolation though. If you have any knowledge of sources that address these kinds of circumstances, I'd be much appreciative if you could point me toward them. Thank you!